# Google Drive & Android - read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

So I have a piece of code which works correctly on all devices and emulators I have access to, except one. It's a cheap old Android device, Huawei Y330-U01, running 4.2.2. I'm compiling with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.8.0`. It's absolutely standard, as far as I can tell.

I get the file, which is over a megabyte of plain text, and I can read it character by character, for a few thousand characters (the amount varies, and not between numbers which are powers of two or anything), before getting the error

```
IOException while testing the stream's first character
java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:486)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
    at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:175)
    at com.suchideas.android.alamode.sync.SyncActivity$b.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:123)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:149)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:476)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179) 
    at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41) 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:175) 
    at com.suchideas.android.alamode.sync.SyncActivity$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm pretty confident this is something like running out of RAM or disk space (there's certainly *more than enough enough* space for this file, by hundreds of megabytes, but the device does like to complain about storage) and clearing away something which was actually in use. Again, to reiterate, **this code works perfectly on emulators of the same Android version, and all other devices tested**.

So. Is there a fix, do you think?

Here's the code, you should be able to fill in the gaps...

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    while (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        try {
            sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        return;
}

appFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient);
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, UPLOADED_DATABASE_NAME))
        .build();
DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult = appFolder.queryChildren(mGoogleApiClient, query).await();
if (!metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    metadataBufferResult.release();
    return;
}

MetadataBuffer databaseFileResults = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
if (databaseFileResults.getCount() == 0) {
    return;
}
Metadata md = databaseFileResults.get(0);
Log.d(TAG, "Database file retrieved [" + md.getFileSize() + "B]. Created " + md.getCreatedDate() + ", modified " + md.getModifiedDate() + ".");
DriveId databaseFileID = md.getDriveId();
databaseFileResults.release();
metadataBufferResult.release();

DriveFile databaseFile = databaseFileID.asDriveFile();
DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = databaseFile.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, new DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(long downloaded, long expected) {

    }
}).await();
if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    return;
}
DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();

InputStream in = driveContents.getInputStream();

try {
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; true; i++) {
        c = in.read();
        if(c == -1) break;
        Log.d(TAG, "Character "+i+": "+(char)c);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException while testing the stream character", e);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so one can almost certainly do better than this (I don't think you need to read character by character, some buffering is probably okay), but after a few hours of battling, I found a way to avoid triggering the issue on this device.

In practice, I would recommend trying a normal `driveContents.getInputStream()` first. Then one can catch the sort of errors discussed above, and only turn to this approach if it becomes necessary.

But it works.

The approach: open the `DriveContents` directly from its `FileDescriptor` rather than through an `InputStream`. Gradually build this up in a buffer (I'm just using a `StringBuilder` here, since this was proof-of-concept). Catch `IOExceptions`, and if you've successfully read at least *some* data, start all over again, and keep going, until you reach the end of the string.

```
private static String safeDriveFileToString(DriveContents driveContents) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    InputStream in;

    int n = 0, nPrevious = 0;
    while(true) {
        in = new FileInputStream(driveContents.getParcelFileDescriptor().getFileDescriptor());
        try {
            int toSkip = n;
            while(toSkip > 0) {
                toSkip -= in.skip(toSkip);
            }

            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) c);
                n++;
            }

            if(c == -1) break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(nPrevious == n) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Ignoring error part-way through a file:", e);
            }
            nPrevious = n;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Wanna know the weirdest thing? After reading this file once with such an approach, it now always works without needing to recourse to this. *Absolutely bizarre.*